# AnyCpu and referenced assembly compiled for several platforms

Tags: .net

I want my library to be compiled for AnyCPU. 
And it should load referenced library for actual platform. (I have ExternalLib.dll for x86 and x64 platforms)

Is it possible with static binding?

Comment: There is no static binding in .NET.  Simply have your installer deploy the 64-bit version of the DLL on a machine with the 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Yeh, wrong words. I meant referencing dll not loading assembly dynamically depending on the platform.